# Merge two tables with different amount

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012

I have two tables (table 1 and table 2) with the same field name.
I want to merge both tables and show the total sum amount present in both table in the result table.

See the example below. Please consider that in table 1 there are 4500 records and table 2 400. 
I tried merge, full join nut can't get the hoped results.

```
Table1
Account_number  Amount
    aaa          100
    bbb           50
    ccc          200
    ddd           20

Table2  
Account_number  Amount
    aaa           85
    bbb           50
    ccc           10
    ddd           40

Result
Account_number  Amount
    aaa          185
    bbb          100
    ccc          210
    ddd           60
```

Comment: Full join should work, could you please post the code ?

Comment: please post your code..

Comment: select dp.account_number,dp.amount+d.amount as TotalAmount
from table1 as dp full outer join Table2 as d
on dp.account_number = d.account_number
where dp.account_number is not null
order by TotalAmount desc

Comment: All the records have the same field bust different records. If I use the full join I get the amount only of the matching data while the non matching one are null

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all Account-Numbers from Table2 also have an entry in Table1 the following statement should work:

```
SELECT Table1.Account_number, Table1.Amount + COALESCE(Table2.Amount, 0)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Account_number=Table2.Account_number;
```

otherwise you could UNION with the same Statement using switched table names:

```
SELECT Table1.Account_number, Table1.Amount + COALESCE(Table2.Amount, 0)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Account_number=Table2.Account_number
UNION
SELECT Table2.Account_number, Table2.Amount + COALESCE(Table1.Amount, 0)
FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Account_number=Table1.Account_number
```

Comment: also, if you want to make it more general, you can change left for full join and and use coalesce to determine account_number and table1.amount too

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(Table1.Account_number,Table2.Account_number), COALESCE(Table1.Amount, 0)   + COALESCE(Table2.Amount, 0)
FROM Table1
FULL JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Account_number=Table2.Account_number;
```

Comment: Awesome it perfectly works ;) Could you please brief explain the coalesce function? Thanks

Comment: coalesce will return the first expression in the list that evaluates to NOT NULL